# Why is Python Open CV imwrite unable to save a simple image from my webcam?

Tags: python, opencv

My goal is to capture some images from my laptop's webcam to use them later. The main problem is that cv2.imwrite doesn't seem to work, the directory is created succesfully but I cannot find a way to save the image. I am currently on Manjaro Linux. I've alredy checked that the frame is not empty and in other Python scripts I've been able to show the image properly, the only problem seems to be when I try to save the image.

Is there any other way to save the image or is something wrong with my code?

I have the following Python code:

```
import cv2 #opencv 
import os
import time
import uuid


IMAGES_PATH = 'Tensorflor/workspace/images/collectedimages'

labels = ['hola', 'gracias', 'si', 'no', 'tequiero']
img_number = 15

for label in labels:
    !mkdir {'Tensorflow/workspace/images/collectedimages/'+label}
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    print('Collecting images for {}'.format(label))
    time.sleep(5)
    for numimg in range(img_number):
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        img_name = os.path.join(IMAGES_PATH, label, label+'.'+'{}.jpg'.format(str(uuid.uuid1())))
        cv2.imwrite(img_name,frame)
        cv2.imshow('Frame',frame)
        time.sleep(2)

        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break
    cap.release()
```

Comment: Do you get an error? Does the script save the image in a different directory than the one you expect? I see a typo in `IMAGES_PATH` that may be causing you trouble (`Tensorflor`).